# What cause the error "ambiguous call to overloaded function"?

Tags: c++

I wrote two methods to return iterator and const_iterator representing the beginning of the list. const_iterator is a class, iterator is a subclass of const_iterator. This first piece of code is copied from the book" Mark A. Weiss - Data Structures & Algorithm Analysis in C++-Prentice Hall (2013)"

```
iterator begin()
{
    iterator itr( head->next );
    return itr;
}

const_iterator begin() const
{
    const_iterator itr{ *this, head };
    return ++itr;
}
```

I want to overload the operator --. But there is an error when I call to the method begin().

```
error C2668: 'List<Square>::begin': ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

```
iterator& operator-- ()
{
    iterator tmp = begin();
    while (tmp->next != current) {
         ++tmp;
    }
    return *this;                
}
```

Comment: Your `operator--` function have a much worse problem: Returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: And what is the reason the constant iterator `begin` *increases* the iterator before returning it?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full error message from the compiler output

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you, I modified `operator--` function

Comment: Are you sure that in the book the code is exactly the same?

Comment: It's not clear, from the code you have provided, what the `operator--()` is a member of.   You need to provide a [mcve] otherwise nobody can help you (since they would have to resort to guesswork, which is notoriously unreliable).